# Using jQuery to position a div relative to another div's bottom border

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I have some HTML that is output via a CMS that I'm unable to modify. The order of this HTML is wrong, in that DIV-Bottom appears before DIV-Top in the HTML.

If DIV-Top was always going to be the same height, I could easily position:absolute DIV-Bottom to appear below DIV-Top. However, DIV-Top differs in height depending on what elements are loaded inside on page load. As a result, I'm trying to find a way using jQuery to look at the bottom border of DIV-Top after page load, and then position DIV-Bottom directly below this.

I believe this can be done with `.offset()` or something similar, but my jQuery knowledge and syntax knowledge is very limited so I'm struggling to make this work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Jamie

Comment: can u show your code here of fiddle so that we can find the errors

Comment: Maybe you're overcomplicating it. Why not just grab the div that's after and put it before? `$('#div2').insertBefore('#div1')`

Comment: it can be done with css alone..no need to complicate it

Comment: what cms? why can't you modify the code generating the html page?

Comment: go and first learn then ask the question.